# Hi. I'm a bit new to programming with vbs. Can someone kind enough, please help me with getting inputbox text and running it as a cmd/batch?

Tags: vbscript

Here is my code, anyone know a way to do this?

```
input = InputBox("Paste the file path you want to delete")

Private Sub button_is_clicked(sender As Object, e As button_clickEventArgs)
      `hmmmmmm, how do I get input to cmd/batch file, I wonder?
End Sub
```

I'm sorry if I am a bit noobish. I'm not really experienced in vbs. With that, I'm pretty new to stack overflow, if I do something wrong, please remind me/tell me. Thank you.

Comment: What is `Obj.Get()`? Some kind of COM component perhaps?

Comment: idk, im new to coding. Otherwise i wouldn't be using this website for help

Comment: So you didn’t write this code then? The `Obj` variable isn't defined there should be a `Set Obj = ...` line to instantiate the object reference. This is the danger of copying code without understanding it, where did the code snippet come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WScript.Shell` object:

```
Dim sCommand
Dim objShell

sCommand = InputBox("Enter command you want to execute:")

Set objShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.run "cmd.exe " & sCommand
```

If you simply want to delete a file, you can use the `FileSystemObject`:

```
Dim sFilePath
Dim objFSO

sFilePath = InputBox("Paste the file path you want to delete:")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists(sFilePath) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sFilePath
```

Comment: This didn't work, thanks anyway. PS: my script is VBScript coding language

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried. This is VBScript code.